# This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have below `xml` that in `RelativeLayout` get me this :

**WARNING :**

```
This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless
```

**XML FILE :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout <--- This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless -->
        android:id="@+id/dings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="8dip">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prgDownload"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dip"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDownload"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="..."
            android:textColor="#afafaf"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice :My `LinearLayout`  is `vertical` but when i use it,it convert to `horizontal` in `Graphical Layout` .

Comment: It's exactly as it says.  The LinearLayout is redundant since all it contains is a RelativeLayout.  Just remove it.

Comment: What is your exact problem we are unable to understand it and already IDE suggesting you that its parent layou is useless means you need to remove that linear layout just keep the relative layout and make it parent for its child

remove linear layout as a parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linear Layout contains a relative layout, which contains the rest of your views. Just remove the linear layout tags and you'll be good to go!

Comment: But i need to Linear Layout .

Comment: What do you need it for? That warning is there because, as your code currently stands, the LinearLayout serves no purpose that the RelativeLayout doesn't already accomplish. If you plan on needing it later, then just ignore the warning.

Comment: I sometimes get this warning when I have linear layout inside a frame because I want a different background colour for the frame, and use padding round the inner layout to achieve that.  I've checked and double checked and in my specific case the warning is wrong.  However, I can think of no reason to put a frame as the only member of a linear layout - you are linearly arranging 1 item.

Comment: If you **NEED** a Linear Layout, then remove the `RelativeLayout` tags

Comment: @Jefferson Why do you need it?  The point of a LinearLayout is to contain 2 or more views, organised in a linear way.  This layout only contains 1 view.  There is nothing to organise!

Comment: @Simon Because I have a loop that I want to have every single result in a new line.

Comment: @Jefferson  You are not understanding this :)  The fact you have a loop (I assume that you are inflating this view in code?), has no bearing on whether you need the LinearLayout or not.  Just try it!

Comment: How i can do my need ?

Comment: @Jefferson  I don't know how to say it differently.  Just remove the LinearLayout.  Actually, you can keep it, the message is a warning, not an error, but it is very inefficient - which is why the warning is given.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are having RelativeLayout wrapped in LinearLayout But Actually your Relative layout is required you just need to remove Linearlayout.

Comment: What do you mean by "Relative layout is required"?